# When using ODE45 on MatLab, inputting numbers with many decimal places for the initial X values and rate constants are causing error messages

Tags: matlab, ode45

I have a function file:

```
function dxdt=function3009(t,x)
% Initialize model vector with zeroes,
dxdt=zeros(5,1);

% Parameters

%% Rate values with many decimal places causing error:
%k1= 1*10^-6;  %     k1*alac*lacI -> LacI-alac
%k2 = 1*10^-13; %     k3*lacI*gop -> LacI-g_op

%% Script runs fine with these instead
k1= 10;  %     k1*alac*lacI -> LacI-alac
k2 = 10; %     k2*lacI*gop -> LacI-g_op


% Differential Equations:
% d[E]/dt
dxdt(1)= - k1*x(1)*x(3) + (k1^-1)*x(2); 
% d[ER]/dt
dxdt(2)=  k1*x(1)*x(3) - (k1^-1)*x(2); 
% d[R]/dt
dxdt(3)=  - k1*x(1)*x(3) + (k1^-1)*x(2) - k2*x(3)*x(4) + (k2^-1) * x(5);
% d[O]/dt
dxdt(4)= - k2*x(3)*x(4) + (k2^-1) * x(5);
% d[OR]/dt  
dxdt(5)= k2*x(3)*x(4) - (k2^-1) * x(5);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and my script file:

```
% Settings
options = odeset('InitialStep',0.1,'MaxStep',0.1);
t_range= [0 10];

%% many decimal points, causes error:
%x_ini= [1*10^-4 0 2*10^-8 0 8.47*10^-12];

%% Runs fine without decimal places:
x_ini= [100 0 10 0 1];

% Simulation
[t,x]=ode45(@function3009,t_range,x_ini,options);

% Plot time series of all variables
subplot(1,3,1);
plot(t,x(:,4:5)); %plot gop and lac:gop 
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Concentration');
title('gop and LacI:gop');
legend('gop', 'lacI:gop');

subplot(1,3,2);
plot(t,x(:,2:3)); %plot lac and lac:alac 
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Concentration');
title('lacI and alac:LacI');
legend('alac:LacI','LacI');

subplot(1,3,3);
plot(t,x(:,1)); %plot alac
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Concentration');
title('Alac');
```

When I run ODE45 with the numbers with many decimal places vs the whole numbers, I receive this error:

Error using horzcat Requested 5x212292600 (7.9GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. 
Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. 
See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

I have 5 DEGs, a time range of 10 with steps of 0.1 (therefore 100 total), so surely the total array size should be 500 regardless of input values? Why does using the input values with many decimal places increase the array size?

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ode becomes numerically stiff when you swap to the "problematic" values. I would suggest using a stiff solver, such as `ode15s`. If you replace that line:

```
[t,x]=ode45(@function3009,t_range,x_ini,options);
```

with that line:

```
[t,x]=ode15s(@function3009,t_range,x_ini,options);
```

It converges really quickly and gives the following results (I can't comment on whether they are correct or not):

[image]

For more details on solver, see [Choose an ODE Solver](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html) in the documentation.